# Spacing issues in a complicated table

Tags: tables, longtable, booktabs

I have a table in which I am including lists in each cell of a column and I am insistent on using vertical lines. At present, I have the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
% \usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{0.05\textwidth}|p{.75\textwidth}|p{0.10\textwidth}|}
  % \toprule
  \hline
    Serial No.\ & Assignment Name & Date \\
    % \midrule
    \hline

    1 
    & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
      Foo bar
      \begin{enumerate}[nosep,after=\strut]
      \item foo
      \item foo
      \item bar
      \item bar
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    & 
    10.01.2022\\
    % \midrule
    \hline

    2
    &
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
      \begin{enumerate}[nosep, after=\strut, label=(\Alph*)]
        \item 
        Given two sequences:
        \[ x_1 = \{\mathbf{2}, 2, 1, 2 \} \]
        \[ x_2 = \{\mathbf{-2}, -1, 3, 2 \} \]
      \end{enumerate} 
      % other items...
      Find their convolution
    \end{minipage}
    &
    17.01.2022\\
    %\bottomrule
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I have two versions:

1. with `booktabs` which gives me more or less proper spacing between the row lines but discontinuous vertical lines (expected of `booktabs`)
   [image]
2. without `booktabs` which removes the discontinuous vertical line but messes up the line spacing (the rows are too close to the horizontal lines separating them):
   [image]

I am looking for an in-between which:

1. gives me proper spacing
2. removes the discontinuous vertical lines.

(It needs to be long table because there are many more entries which will together span 3 pages at least.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of the `tabularray` package:

[image]

To adjust the space between horizontal line and text, use the `abovesep` and `belowsep` and keys. (The default value is `2pt`.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label*=\arabic*.,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  nosep,
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
                  after=\end{minipage}}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{colspec={l X l}, hlines, vlines, measure = vbox}
    {Serial\\ No.} & Assignment Name & Date \\
    1 
    & 
      Foo bar
      \begin{tabenum}
      \item foo
      \item foo
      \item bar
      \item bar
    \end{tabenum}
    & 
    10.01.2022\\

    2
    &
      \begin{tabenum}[label=(\Alph*)]
        \item 
        Given two sequences:
        \[ x_1 = \{\mathbf{2}, 2, 1, 2 \} \]
        \[ x_2 = \{\mathbf{-2}, -1, 3, 2 \} \]
      \end{tabenum} 
       %other items...
      Find their convolution
    &
    17.01.2022\\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this solution with the `cellspace` package  will be fine for you. This package ensures a minimal vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` by default (or `C` if you load `siunitx`,  or any letter you please with the `column=some letter` option).

I also removed the  `minipage` environments which are unnecessary here since you use the `p` column type.

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}

    \usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{cellspace}
    \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{8pt}
    \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{8pt}


    \begin{document}

    \begin{longtable}{|p{0.05\textwidth}|S{p{.75\textwidth}}|p{0.10\textwidth}|}
      % \toprule
      \hline
        Serial No.\ & Assignment Name & Date \\
        % \midrule
        \hline
        1
        &
          Foo bar
          \begin{enumerate}[nosep,after=\strut]
          \item foo
          \item foo
          \item bar
          \item bar
        \end{enumerate}
        &
        10.01.2022\\
        \hline
    %
        2
        & \begin{enumerate}[nosep, after=\strut, label=(\Alph*)]
            \item
            Given two sequences:
            \[ x_1 = \{\mathbf{2}, 2, 1, 2 \} \]
            \[ x_2 = \{\mathbf{-2}, -1, 3, 2 \} \]
          \end{enumerate}
          % other items...
          Find their convolution
        &
        17.01.2022 \\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You're wrong about vertical lines, but that's personal opinion.

Rather than using minipages, you need to remove spurious blank lines before or after a list.

```
\documentclass[11pt,draft]{article}

\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|p{.75\textwidth}|l|}
\hline
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}Serial \\ No.\end{tabular} & Assignment Name & Date \\
\hline
1 &
  Foo bar
  \begin{enumerate}[nosep,after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}]
    \item foo
    \item foo
    \item bar
    \item bar
  \end{enumerate} & 
  10.01.2022\\
\hline
2 & 
  \begin{enumerate}[nosep, wide, label=(\Alph*),before=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}]
    \item Given two sequences:
      \begin{gather*}
        x_1 = \{\mathbf{2}, 2, 1, 2 \} \\
        x_2 = \{\mathbf{-2}, -1, 3, 2 \}
      \end{gather*}
    \item Given two sequences:
      \begin{gather*}
        x_1 = \{\mathbf{2}, 2, 1, 2 \} \\
        x_2 = \{\mathbf{-2}, -1, 3, 2 \}
      \end{gather*}
  \end{enumerate} 
  Find their convolution &
  17.01.2022\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would (a) get rid of all vertical bars -- they aren't needed, and they won't be missed -- and (b) calculate the width of the middle column as a residual, to assure that the column's width is maximized.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,enumitem,longtable,amsmath}
\newlength\mylenA
\settowidth\mylenA{Serial No.}
\newlength\mylenB
\settowidth\mylenB{10.01.2022}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{} p{\mylenA}
                      p{\dimexpr\textwidth-\mylenA-\mylenB-4\tabcolsep\relax}
                      p{\mylenB} @{}}
  \toprule
  Serial No. & Assignment Name & Date \\
  \midrule
  \endhead
    
  \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot

    1 
    & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
      Foo bar
      \begin{enumerate}[nosep,after=\strut]
      \item foo
      \item foo
      \item bar
      \item bar
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    & 
    10.01.2022 \\
    \midrule

    2
    &
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
      \begin{enumerate}[nosep, after=\strut, label=(\Alph*)]
        \item 
        Given two sequences:
        \[ 
        \begin{aligned}
          x_1 &= \{\mathbf{2},   2, 1, 2 \} \\
          x_2 &= \{\mathbf{-2}, -1, 3, 2 \}
          \end{aligned}
        \]
      % other items...
      Find their convolution
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    &
    17.01.2022\\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```